# How to set AIMMS to follow a script, so as to keep running for a certain number of times?

Tags: aimms

Objective function:

```
(X*Y1+(1-X)*Y2)*Z
```

Subject to some constraints:

If x starts from 0 I will have an optimal solution OS1
then I need run again with an increment of 0.01 for x, so if x=0.01 there will be OS2. continuing the process there will be OS1 to OS100.

Is there a way that I can program aimms to run all increments and then select the max among OS1 to OS100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this as follows:

1. Create a set "AllSolutions" with 101 elements and index s.
2. Create a parameter "SolutionObjective(s)"
3. Create a procedure with the following body:
   for s do
    x := (ord(s)-1)/card(AllSolutions);
    Solve ;
    SolutionObjective(s) := ;
   endfor;
4. The parameter SolutionObjective contains the 101 solutions that you are looking for. You can retrieve the max via the following statement:
   Max(s, SolutionObjective(s));
5. The corresponding x is:
   x := (ord(argmax(s, SolutionObjective(s)))-1)/100.

Regards,

Peter Nieuwesteeg

Senior AIMMS Specialist.

Comment: Thank you sir. This would help a lot. I have another question, what if I have multiple excel files containing different sets of data. I upload each excel file to aimms which gives me 1 optimal solution, how would i program aimms such that it would run all my excel files? can this be done also?

Comment: how about the corresponding variables for of each optimal solution, can i also retrieve them all?